# firmware grow bigger after enable gcc coverage

Tags: android, gcc, code-coverage

I am implementing gcov on an android device, and it's system image has a size limitation. My problem is that the system image grow 7M or more after I enable gcov by adding

```
my_cflags += --coverage
my_ldflags += --coverage
```

in build/core/binary.mk
Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, gcov adds more code and runtime libs to your program to track branches, etc. so this is expected. You may consider compiling with `-Os` to alleviate this.